# Hive Server 1 vs Hive Server 2

Tags: hive

We have hive 0.10 version and we were wondering if we should be using Hive Server 1 or Hive Server2. Another question is to connect to Hive Server running on port 10000, using 3rd party tools do we need anything else?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

I had the Hive 1 v 2 question and found the basics at:

http://www.slideshare.net/cwsteinbach/hiveserver2-for-apache-hive

- HiveServer2 Thrift API spec
- JDBC/ODBC HiveServer2 drivers
- Concurrent Thrift clients with memory leak fixes and session/config
  info
- Kerberos authentication
- Authorization to improve GRANT/ROLE and code injection vectors

I'm sure there's more given intervening development.

Answer (score 2):

Hive Server 2 supports Rest API. Tools like beeline can be used to connect from any client outside of your cluster to the hive database. In a secured environment beeline(Hive Rest API client) will connect through knox gateway. Literally there can be multiple beeline connections possible to connect with Hive Server2. So, go with hiveserver2 for more secured and to have multiple connections

Answer (score 2):

HiveServer2 is an improved version of HiveServer that supports a Thrift API tailored for JDBC and ODBC clients, Kerberos authentication, and multi-client concurrency. The CLI for HiveServer2 is Beeline.

Src: Cloudera

Answer (score 0):

Kerberos (authentication) and  Sentry (authorization).
Sentry security will working through HiveServer2 and HiveServer1 which is used by Hive CLI.
The CLI for HiveServer1 is HiveCLI.
The CLI for HiveServer2 is Beeline.